# ontouch for RecycleView affects other positions

Tags: android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener, android-studio-3.0

I have a RecyclerView that I want to add a colored place holder so that when the user clicks on an item, that item and all before become colored. If the previous item clicked was an item after it I'll uncolor that and the other items that come after the current item clicked.

I've gotten it to color any item clicked but I'm not sure how to handle one click affecting other items like that

Answer (score 0):

I had the clicks be represented by a boolean[](true = selected, false = not selected). When a position is selected make that position true and the ones before it true and the ones after it false.

I then call notifydatasetchanged which starts up OnBindViewHolder to set the colors based of if the positions are true or false